# Difference between Alon-Tarsi number and the list chromatic number

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

The Alon-Tarsi number is the least number $k$ such that the coefficient with degree $d$ of the graph polynomial $P(G)=\prod\limits_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$,( where $x_i$ corresponds to a vertex and a term $x_i-x_j$ occurs iff there is an edge in the graph from vertex $i\to j$) is nonzero  for $d<k$.

By Combinatorial Nullstellensatz, it is known that the list chromatic number of the graph is less than or equal to its Alon-Tarsi number. My question is, are there easy examples of graphs with list chromatic number strictly less than the Alon-Tarsi number; and what can be abound for the gap between the list chromatic number and the Alon-Tarsi number? Is it arbitrarily large? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The paper by Kaul-Mudrock *On the Alon-Tarsi Number and Chromatic-Choosability of Cartesian Products of Graphs" (https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v26i1p3/pdf ) seems highly relevant. In particular, at the very end of page 4 they state that "$\chi(G)\le\chi_l(G)\le\chi_p(G)\le AT(G). $ In general all these inequalities can be strict".

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the graph $K_{n,n}$. Since the graph polynomial of $K_{n,n}$ is homogenous with degree $n^2$, we must have the Alon-Tarsi number of the graph $K_{n,n}$ to be $\ge \frac{n^2}{2n}=\frac{n}{2}$.

However, it is well known that the list chromatic number or the choice number of $K_{n,n}$ is bounded above by $\log_2n+2$. This bound is obtained by using a weighting and coloring argument: At each step, we color a certain set of vertices and double the weight on the remaining set of vertices. The procedure is repeated till long, from which the bound $\log_2n+2$ is obtained. Full proof can be found in the great book "Combinatorial Nullstellensatz" by X Zhu and R Balakrishnan [here](https://www.routledge.com/Combinatorial-Nullstellensatz-With-Applications-to-Graph-Colouring/Zhu-Balakrishnan/p/book/9780367686949)